# Nativeprocess bug

Tags: apache-flex, air

The NativeProcess is having a big issue which would hang/sudden stop response after 1-2 mins of running. I wonder if anyone else encounter the same issue?

I have tested on Windows 7 (64bit).

If there any way to launch an exe and release the Nativeprocess handler from monitoring the process or other method will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some proxy executable which runs exe you need and then exits. For a quick patch, cmd.exe with argument /C will do (it means "execute single command and exit"). Second argument must be name of target executable (with respect of current directory).

Comment: I tried that method in my above question and it will also indirectly hang the process from the proxy executable. It was totally strange, without exiting the AIR application, I launch another application process, the AIR was able to continue animate.

Comment: http://bugs.adobe.com/flashplayer/ - you may look here. If you are sure, register and file a bug.

Comment: Already file a bug last week but one of the assignees have not even reply or checking my submission. What to do, I getting shitty issue. http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-28473